# List based quest system

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hi guys I'm trying to build a list based quest system in unity. Everything is working except this bit of code here:

```
for (int i = currentPoints; i >= 0; i++)
    {
        if (Quests[i].pointsRequired <= currentPoints)
        {
            Debug.Log("ping"); 
            currentQuestid += 1;
        }
    }
```

I'm not too sure why but any suggestions or help would be great thanks!!

Full script:

public class questManager : MonoBehaviour
{
public int currentQuestid;

```
[System.Serializable]
public class Quest
{
    public int pointsRequired;
    public GameObject objects;
    public int questID;
    public string objective;
    public string pointName;
    public string info;
    public float waitTime;
    public bool enabled = false;
    public Text objectiveText;
    public Text remainingText;
    public Text infoText;
}

public Quest[] Quests;
public int currentPoints;
public float currentdelay;
public int required;

void Start()
{
    currentQuestid = 0;
    currentPoints = 0;
    

    for (int i = 0; i < Quests.Length; i++)
    {
        Quests[i].objectiveText.text = Quests[i].objective;
    }
}

void Update()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Quests.Length; i++)
    {
        Quests[i].objects.SetActive(i == currentQuestid);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < Quests.Length; i++)
    {
        Quests[i].remainingText.text = Quests[i].pointName + ": " + currentPoints + "/" + Quests[i].pointsRequired;
    }

    for (int i = currentPoints; i >= 0; i++)
    {
        if (Quests[i].pointsRequired <= currentPoints)
        {
            Debug.Log("ping"); 
            currentQuestid += 1;
        }
    }


}`
```

Comment: what does 'not working' mean?  Errors, no results, wrong results, etc.

Comment: No errors it just never seems to run the if statement

Comment: The current logic for the loop in question is `start at currentPoints and add one while greater than or equal to 0`. Is this the intended behavior? It is atypical to _add_ to the incrementer with a condition of _greater than_. The iterator (`i`) will never break that condition on its own. If `currentPoints` is eq to 0, the loop will run at least once. So check your `if` condition if you're seeing _nothing_ printed.

Answer (score 1):

Simple typo in `for` loop:

```
for (int i = currentPoints; i >= 0; --i)
{
    //Be safe
    if (Quests.Length <= i)
        continue;
    if (Quests[i].pointsRequired <= currentPoints)
    {
        Debug.Log("ping"); 
        currentQuestid += 1;
    }
}
```

Specifically, you want to decrement `i`, not increment it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but still no luck :/

Comment: @TomGB - We don't know what is wrong with your current code. Can you share the error, etc, that you're getting? Is the code in this answer giving you the same error?

Comment: No error or anything. It just doesn't seem to run the if statement. That why I wasn't sure either